# How to toggle values on rails check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have rails form_tag and I need to add a checkbox that can toggle the values true or false.

I have this code:

```
 <%= form_tag(admin_workorder_denture_design_messages_path(workorder), method: "post", class: 'comment_form', id: 'workorder_form') do %>
      <div>
        <%= text_area_tag(:message, '', class: "form-control workorder_notes_text_area") %>
      </div>

      <div class="mt-5 text-right">
        <%= check_box_tag("Send Email to customer",checked = false)%>

        <%= submit_tag("Submit", type:"submit", class:"btn btn-primary", id: 'workorder_notes_button')  %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

when I submit the this from and toggle the check box for some reason it doesnt change value, it'll always be false even though I checked it. I think it's because of `tagged form`. I have a `form_for` and a checkbox and it toggles the value.

Question is how can you achieve the same behavior with `check_box_tag`?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37073266/10895713

Comment: @MaxVinícius saw that but I'm not using jquery and I'm not using ajax to send a request. this goes from rails view to controller.

Comment: You have `checked = false`, you are always showing it unchecked. You are not showing your controller either, nor the console log of the request, add more information, it's confusing.

Comment: @arieljuod uhhmm. `checked = false` is the initial state of the checked box, controller has nothing yet. nothing to show. I'm just grabbing the params and checking the values that are coming in. is there something that I miss?

Comment: The signature of the `check_box_tag` method is `check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`, you are not sending the paremeters the right way, you are missing the name of the field. Show the generated HTML, also show the params hash. I don't understand your description of the problem, you say you submit the form and then toggle the checkbox? also "value" is an attribute that does not change on check boxes, it's sent or not sent depending on the state but the value does not change.